# Why does `perl -pe 's/$/\n/g'` add 2 blank lines?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working through the one liner book and came across

```
perl -pe 's/$/\n/' file
```

which inserts a blank line after each line by setting the end of the line to new line thus adding a new line to the existing newline  resulting in a blank line.
As this is the first example without `g` at the end of the pattern, I tried

```
perl -pe 's/$/\n/g' file
```

this results in 2 blank lines between lines.
I would have expected no difference since there is only one `$` per line so replacing all of them should be the same as replacing just the first one.
What's going on here?

Comment: Try removing `g` modifier. Also, try using `\z` instead of `$`.

Comment: [perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) says about `$`: `Match the end of the string (or before newline at the endof the string)`. It does not match the newline itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/$/` matches the “end of string”. This might be

- the end of string (like `/\z/`),
- or just before a newline before the end of string (like `/(?=\n\z)/`).

(Additionally, `/$/m` matches the “end of line”. This might be

- the end of string,
- or just before a newline (like `/(?=\n)/`).

).

With your substitution `/$/\n/g`, the regex matches twice: once before the newline, then again at the end of string:

- The first match is before the newline:

  ```
  "foo\n"
  #   ^ match
  ```

  A newline is placed before the current match end:

  ```
  "foo\n\n"
  #     ^ insert before
  ```
- The next match is at the end of string:

  ```
  "foo\n\n"
  #       ^ match
  ```

  A newline is inserted before the current match end:

  ```
   "foo\n\n\n"
   #         ^ insert before
  ```
- No further match is found.

The solution: if `$` is to DWIMmy for you, always match `\z` or `\n` explicitly, possibly together with lookaheads like `(?=\n)`. Consider matching all Unicode line separators `\R` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Input has nothing to do with the `$` or `\z` metacharacters, and it's deceptive to fabricate a concept like *end of input* which doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: @Borodin Good point, sorry for the confusion. I've corrected “input” → “string“. But in the future, please assume a honest mistake rather than malice (“deceptive to fabricate”). You also have more than enough rep to make this edit yourself when you spot a problem!

Comment: "End of input" is an idea that didn't exist beyond *end of file* or *timeout* on a file descriptor, so you made it up; hence *"fabricate"*. I realise that it can have negative connotations, but would you prefer *"invent*, *"devise"*, or something else? I am quite happy with *"deceptive"*:  it doesn't imply mendacity, and while I would consider *"misleading"* I don't think it would make much difference. I always prefer to indicate potential improvements to posts in comments so that the author can modify their own post if they agree. I find that most people prefer to retain their agency.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a sound understanding of the situation. `$` is a badly-defined and unintuitive metacharacter

- It is a *zero-width match*
- It will match *before a newline character* at the end of the bound string
- It will match *at the end of the bound string*
- With the `/m` modifier in place, it will also match *before any newline character anywhere*, but not immediately after it unless it is the last character of the string

`\z` is much more useful: it only ever matches at the end of the string

*"by setting the end of the line to new line"*

Mentioning "lines" at all is misleading, and you should be careful to explain in comments what meaning you're applying. If you have

```
my $s = "xxx\n"
```

then

```
say pos($s) while $s =~ /$/g
```

will produce

```
3
4
```

i.e. both *before* and *after* the newline, because it happens to be at the end of the string

This is also why your `s/$/\n/g` adds two newlines: there are two zero-width matches for `/$/` within this string, and a global substitution finds them and replaces them both with a newline, resulting in three newlines instead of the original one

It's unclear what you intended

- Adding a newline to the end of a string, regardless of what's there already is `s/\z/\n/` or just `$s .= "\n"`
- If you want to ensure that, say, there are exactly two newlines at the end of a string, then just remove any existing linefeeds first with `s/\n+\z/\b\n/`

As you can see, `\z` is much more useful than `$`

And don't forget `\R` if you're dealing with cross-platform data. It will match any standard line terminator: any of CR, LF or CRLF

If this still leaves you with a problem then please ask again. I was going to write about *zero-width* matches but it's hard to know whether my answer is clear without it